# use Regex within Php Code

Tags: php, javascript, regex

hi this is my Regex code

```
 var concatedString = concatedSubstring.replace(/\//g, '-').replace(/([0-9])([a-zA-     Z])/g,"$1-$2").replace(/[A-Za-z]/g, function(c){
            return c.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0)-64;
```

I am trying to convert it to PHP regex what I have done is

```
 $pin = preg_replace('{/\//g}', '-', $pin);
             $pin = preg_replace('{/([0-9])([a-zA-Z])/g}','$1-$2', $pin);
             $pin3 = preg_replace('{/[A-Za-z]/g}', strtoupper($pin), $pin );
             echo $pin3;
```

I cant progress any further.

Comment: have you tried taking out those '{' and '}' in your regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need those `{}` around everything.

Also, in your last `preg_replace`, you're matching `[a-zA-Z]` and replacing with upper-case - but if it's upper case in the first place, there's no need to replace it:

```
$pin = preg_replace('/\//', '-', $pin);
$pin = preg_replace('/([0-9])([a-zA-Z])/','$1-$2', $pin);
// only need to convert lowercase to uppercase.
$pin3 = preg_replace('/[a-z]/', strtoupper($pin), $pin ); 
echo $pin3;
```

Comment: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier 'g' i am getting this after i used your code.

Comment: I didn't look at the modifier that closely, but this may help you: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: There's no `g` modifier in `preg_replace`.

Comment: Thanks, forgot `preg_replace` is global. Will edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need the curly braces around your regex's.  Second of all, the strtoupper isn't going to work the way you've done it, but you're not far off.

```
<?php
$pin = preg_replace('/\//', '-', $pin);
$pin = preg_replace('/([0-9])([a-zA-Z])/','$1-$2', $pin);
$pin3 = strtoupper($pin);
echo $pin3;
?>
```